# Le deuxième couplet de la chanson québécoise « le couteau »

Tags: sens, québec, paroles-de-chanson

Vous voyez ci-dessous un morceau de la chanson québécoise qui s’appelle « le couteau ». Le groupe auquel je la dois s’appelle « Mes souliers sont rouge ». *Aidez-moi à mieux comprendre le déroulement du récit s’il vous plaît.*

> Mon bon Monsieur, je suis trop gueux,
>   Quel gâchis vous ferais-je !
>   Je suis pieds nus, sales et boueux
>   Et tout couvert de neige !
>
> Mon pauvre ami, quitte bien vite
>   Tes hardes en lambeaux :
>   Pouille-moi ce tricot, de suite
>   Chausse-moi ces sabots !

Je dirais que les quatre premières lignes sont les propos du sans-abri, et que les autres appartiennent au métayer. Le sans-abri frappe à la porte du métayer pour lui prier de dormir dans sa grange. Puis le métayer lui dit qu’il vaut mieux dormir dans sa maison. Le gueux a alors peur de la salir et il en prévient le métayer. Puis je pense que le métayer lui prête d’autres vêtements, mais j’en doute.

**Une tentative de tout exprimer autrement**:

**Le gueux**

> Mon bon Monsieur, je suis trop ignoble
>   Comme je salirais vôtre maison !
>   Mes pieds son nus, sales et boueux
>   Et tout couvert de neige !

**Le métayer**

> Mon pauvre ami, enlève vite
>   Tes vêtements déchirés
>   laisse-moi enfiler ton vêtement tricoté, et après
>   Laisse-moi chausser tes sabots !

Je suis dans l’incertitude de la fonction du mot « harde ». Le mot désigne un troupeau de bêtes, mais le récit laisse croire que c'est un vêtement. L’emploi du mot *pouiller* m’étonne aussi. Pensez-vous qu’on l’ait confondu avec *dépouiller* ? C’est aussi un peu étrange que le métayer veuille mettre les sabots du sans-abri alors qu’il n’en a pas.

Answer (score 3):

> *Hardes* (toujours au pluriel) ensemble des effets personnels (vêtement, linges et mes meubles voyageant avec les bagages) - Le Robert.

N.B. : Autrefois à la St-Michel les baux ruraux prenaient fin, on voyait alors les paysans qui devaient changer de ferme emporter tout leurs biens, leurs *hardes* (souvent de maigres bagages) sur une charrette en même temps, les manouvriers un ballot à l'épaule.

*Pouiller* est un mot ancien et inusité dans le sens donné par [*le Littré*](http://www.littre.org/definition/pouiller). À moins qu'il s'agisse d'un québécisme, cela ressemble plutôt à une construction poétique :  si je te ***dé***pouille en t'enlevant tes vêtements, je te *pouille* en t'enfilant ces vêtements.

On peut reformuler ainsi :

- Tes hardes en lambeaux → tes vêtements en lambeaux.
- Pouille-moi ce tricot, de suite → enfile-moi ce tricot, de suite.
- Chausse-moi ces sabot → Mets ces sabot à tes pieds.

Le *moi* ne renvoie pas aux sabots du locuteur, mais indique un ordre que le locuteur impose au mendiant.

Comment: Merci pour avoir répondu ! Quand le métayer parle, pourquoi est-ce que le mot « pouille » est suivi de « moi » si c’est son pauvre hôte qui doit mettre les vêtements ? Et pourquoi est-ce que vous avez fait la même chose en le remplaçant par enfile ?

Comment: *Je te demandes* d'enfiler ce tricot, de mettre ces sabots, de ...

Comment: Si je devais analyser la grammaire de 'chausse-moi', ce serait comme 'dis-moi': 'dis à moi', 'dis et je reçois l'action', et donc par extension 'dis pour moi', c'est un datif. Donc 'chausse-moi' veut dire 'put on for me', c'est un ordre doux et familier, 'fais le pour moi','do me a favor and put this on'.

Answer (score 1):

Je crois que vous avez bien capté le sens des 4 phrases du sans-abri et les premières deux phrases du métayer, car « hardes » peut vouloir dire « vêtements pauvres et usagés ».

Pour les phrases 3 et 4 du métayer,  moi je vois plutôt que la générosité du métayer va même plus loin que « Ma maison est votre maison  » jusqu'au point qu’il veut dire « mes pieds sont vos pieds » et « mon corps est le vôtre » quand il dit  « pouille*-moi ce tricot (mettez ce pull-over chaud sur moi=VOUS) et « chausse-moi ces sabots (mettez ces sabots sur mes=VOS pieds)

*pouiller= •  (Familier) Mettre quelque chose dans une autre.

*(par contre, peut-être parle-t-il de « éliminer ses=VOS poux de votre pull-over » car « se pouiller » peut dire "éliminer ses poux", mais l’idée de « le mien est le votre » reste, je crois)

Donc le voila ce que je vous propose :

Le gueux/sans-abri

```
Mon bon Monsieur, je suis trop ignoble
Comme je salirais votre maison !
Mes pieds son nus, sales et boueux
Et tout couvert de neige !
```

Le métayer

```
Mon pauvre ami, enlève vite
Tes vêtements déchirés
```

> Mets-toi ce pull-over (pour me faire plaisir), et puis
>
> (ou peut-être : Élimine/tue les poux sur ton pull, et puis)
>
> Chausse-toi ces sabots (pour me faire plaisir)!