# Le cinquième couplet de la chanson canadienne « le couteau »

Tags: sens, québec, paroles-de-chanson

Ceci est un morceau coriace de la chanson « [le couteau](http://musique.ados.fr/Mes-Souliers-Sont-Rouges/Le-Couteau-t26602.html) » du groupe « mes souliers sont rouges ». C’est la troisième fois que je demande quelque chose sur cette chanson, donc j’ai ajouté un lien vers [ma première question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12385/le-deuxi%C3%A8me-couplet-de-la-chanson-qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9coise-le-couteau) pour que tout le monde puisse voir de quoi il retourne sans tout écouter.

- Chassez du coin de votre feu ce rôdeur qui ne bouge.
- Etes-vous "Blanc" ? Êtes-vous "Bleu" ? Moi, je suis plutôt "Rouge" !
- Qu'importent ces mots : République, commune ou Royauté" :
- Ne mêlons pas la Politique avec la Charité !

Je perds le fil rouge ici. Je crois que c’est le métayer qui cause. Je ne sais pas qui est « le rôdeur qui ne bouge » C’est peut-être le gueux mais cela ne cadrerait pas avec l’histoire.

La deuxième chose que je ne saisis pas est ce qui les couleurs veulent dire.  J’ai cherché des renseignements au moyen de Google, mais sans beaucoup trouver. On pourrait penser que ses propos aient quelque chose à voir avec le drapeau français, mais s’il en était ainsi je dirais que le métayer devrait dire les couleurs dans un autre ordre. Y-a-t-il quelque chose de canadien dont il faut avoir connaissance pour tout comprendre ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Je ne sais pas qui est « le rôdeur qui ne bouge »

J'y trouve trois possibilités (et, peut-être qu'il y a quand même une autre, plus correcte que les miennes).

Je ne suis pas du tout certain ; mais à mon avis peut-être que le chanteur s’adressait à nous. C'est nous qui sommes des rôdeurs fainéants, nous ne nous bougeons pas de devant notre propre feu, mais il vaudrai mieux que nous nous déplacions pour accueillir les gueux et leur donner du pain.

Mais selon [ce video](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xgfrtj_lecouteau-mes-souliers-sont-rouges-botrel-brouwer_creation) le rôdeur est un tiers, qui n'a pas parlé : peut-être que c'est un "blanc" ou un "bleu".

Par contre, [dans cet illustration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V9F1kcDqEoQ) j'ai l'impression que "chassez ce rôdeur" est un conseil que quelqu'un donne au métayer, au sujet du pauvre ami ; et que la suite du couplet est la réponse du métayer, qui dit qu'il faut ignorer la politique (ou favoriser le communisme qui est synonyme de charité).

---

> La deuxième chose que je ne saisis pas est ce qui les couleurs veulent dire.

L'auteur des paroles est [Théodore Botrel](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9odore_Botrel) et donc il ne faut pas y chercher de symboles canadiens.

[Le rouge est sans doute socialiste](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drapeau_rouge) ou communiste.

[Ici](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_France) et [ici](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g-cq1gcXUcc) on donne plusieurs interprétations, parmis lesquelles, le blanc est la royauté, et le bleu la République ou la bourgeoisie.

Je suis sûr que les trois couleurs sont donc des symboles politiques, dont le rouge est le plus important. Dans le video, le pauvre ami fait le [geste du poing gauche levé](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poing_lev%C3%A9) en prononçant le mot "rouge".